# .append() <li> elements of one <ul> to another <ul>

Tags: jquery, html

Consider:

```
<ul>
    <li class="abc">one</li>
    <li class="abc">two</li>
    <li class="abc">three</li>
</ul>

<ul class="target"></ul>
```

What exactly happens when I do the following?

```
$('.target').append($('.abc'));
```

I suspect all `<li>` elements to get removed from the first `<ul>` and get inserted into `'ul.target'`.  Would the event handlers attached to `<li>`'s get removed?

Comment: why don't you try this?

Comment: I did. Getting weird behavior.  Just want to see what the public has to say about this.

Comment: @Dimskiy then maybe update the post with what you already found, to save everybody time!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

http://api.jquery.com/append/

> If an element selected this way is inserted into a single location
>   elsewhere in the DOM, it will be moved into the target (not cloned):

Presumably `not cloned` means event handlers don't get transferred.

However, it goes on to say:

> If there is more than one target element, however, cloned copies of
>   the inserted element will be created for each target after the first.

That means that because there are multiple elements, event handlers DO get transferred, as demonstrated here:

http://jsbin.com/UMUHOVe/1/edit

```
  <h1>list one</h1>
  <ul>
    <li class="abc">one</li>
    <li class="abc">two</li>
    <li class="abc">three</li>
</ul>

  <a href="#">Transfer</a>

  <h1>list two</h1>
<ul class="target"></ul>

$(document).ready(function() {
  $(".abc").each(function() {
    $(this).click(function() {
      console.log("hi");
    });
  });
  $("a").click(function(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
$('.target').append($('.abc'));
  });
});
```

Comment: Cool! Thanks! Pretty much, all I wanted to hear.

Comment: Ok! That's exactly where I was puzzling! I had a different behavior for the first element vs. the rest of them.

Comment: I know this comment will get deleted, but will you people stop downrating things here? He actually did help me.